# Migration does not work with Timestamp after update to EF 6.1

Tags: entity-framework, migration

I just upgraded my ASP.NET MVC project to Entity Framework 6.1.

What I thought was strange: I also had to add an migration, which basically drops some primary and foreign keys, changes a few columns, and then recreates the keys. All models have a hierarchy-relationship, i.e. I have a class "Person" and inherit "Teacher", "Student" etc. Then I map this to a table-per-type-hierarchy.

The affected properties in my Person-model were:

```
public Byte[] Timestamp { get; set; }
```

This property is defined as rowversion:

```
Property(p => p.Timestamp).IsRowVersion();
```

Code for Up-migration:

```
AlterColumn("dbo.Teachers", "timestamp", c => c.Binary());
```

The other affected property (also Person-class):

```
public int PersonId { get; set; }
```

In entity config defined as:

```
Property(p => p.PersonId)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
```

This one is the primary key. The created migration:

```
AlterColumn("dbo.Teachers", "PersonId", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
```

Two remarks:
1) I define the "IsRowVersion" config for each inherited entity
2) I also define the primary key config for each inherited entity

The error I get when I execute the migration:
    Cannot alter column 'timestamp' because it is 'timestamp'.

I spent two evenings with google, but did not find this problem anywhere... Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, spent another evening with this topic. Finally, I found the solution - with these changes,  EF 6.1 does not create a migration!

So, what's the trick? This all is only happening when you use TPT (table per type in a hierarchy).

My mistake: I made the configurations (see question above) regarding primary key and rowversion for EACH type separately! Now, I moved these configs to the base type config (which I did not have at all before), and removed them from the child types. Then it works.

Hope it helps someone...